# Navigation Drawer for Multiple activities

Tags: android

Hello i am new to android. I would like to implement navigation drawer consisting of a list of items, which when clicked opens a new activity. Basically a navigation drawer across all the activities. When I select an item from the navigation drawer that particular activity opens but the icon for the navigation drawer (hamburger icon) disappears. How do I get that?

NavBaseActivity.java

```
package app.pal.study.samplestudy;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;

public class NavBaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
private DrawerLayout drawer;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_nav_base);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
   // getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    //getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.nav_base, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();


    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
   /* if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);*/
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            drawer.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.item_home) {
        // Handle the camera action
        startActivity(new Intent(this, Home.class));

    } else if (id == R.id.item_syllabus) {
        startActivity(new Intent(this, Syllabus.class));


    } else if (id == R.id.item_study_time) {
        startActivity(new Intent(this, StudyTime.class));


    } else if (id == R.id.item_exam) {
        startActivity(new Intent(this, Exam.class));


    } else if (id == R.id.item_calendar) {
        startActivity(new Intent(this, Calendar.class));


    } else if (id == R.id.nav_scribble) {
        startActivity(new Intent(this, Scribble.class));


    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
// `onPostCreate` called when activity start-up is complete after `onStart()`
// NOTE! Make sure to override the method with only a single `Bundle` argument
@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
}
```

}

Syllabus.java

```
package app.pal.study.samplestudy;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;

public class Syllabus extends NavBaseActivity implements         NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_syllabus);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton)          findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });
}
```

}

activity_nav_base.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:openDrawer="start">

<include
    layout="@layout/app_bar_nav_base"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_nav_base"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_nav_base_drawer" />

    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is advised to use Navigation Drawer with fragments as it will maintain the nav drawer. You have to convert your activities in fragments. Please check developer link- http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html

Comment: Thank u. But is there some way i could modify this program which i have already done.

Comment: @Khadija - It is better to correct your program when you find out the mistake rather than continue implementing in the wrong way which can lead you to other problems as well.

Answer (score 0):

Has anyone figured out how to get this method of one main activity pushing in fragments to work with the back button ?

Everything works fine going "forward", and all the fragments get pulled into the content frame, but as soon as you hit the back button, the application closes...most likely because it is the only activity running and the back button closes the activity.

Anyway to put code in to get the fragment manager to go back to the last fragment and not close the activity on the back button ?

Comment: `addToBackStack` will help